# Time Complexity C

Tags: c, complexity-theory

```
void f(int n) {
 int x = n;
 while (x * x > n) {
   x /= 2;
   printf (“x cubed = %d\n”, x * x * x);
 }
 while (x > 0)
   x--;
 printf("hello %d\n", x);
}
```

I don't understan how they got **complexity of TETA(sqrt(n))**... can someone explain me the formal way how to find complexity of this alghorithem, and others like this..? do I need to make a Tracking table?
is there any site that gives examples on alghorithems and there complexities?

10x a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you exit the first while cycle:

```
 while (x * x > n) {
   x /= 2;
   printf (“x cubed = %d\n”, x * x * x);
 }
```

You will have x in the interval `[sqrt(n)/2, sqrt(n)]` and after that you execute x iterations of the next cycle. First cycle has complexity of the order of `log(n)` and thus the overall complexity is theta of sqrt(n) as defined by the second cycle(`log(n)` grows slower than `sqrt(n)`).

Comment: 10x for the quick answer! I'm still having some troubles with understanding it completely.. do you have sites with examples and explanations about this subject maybe?

Comment: In this case the source is my own knowledge. I have been teaching design and analysis of computer algorithms for some years now. I personally used "Introduction to algorithms" as source of knowledge for complexity analysis back in the day.